# sed: Insert a string containing path delimeters

Tags: sed

I want to insert a line into a file at line 13 using sed. This is what I tried:

```
sed -i '13/home/me/dostuff.py &' /etc/rc.local
```

I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command : `/'
```

How do I insert text containing slashes at a given line using sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
sed -i '13i\/home/me/dostuff.py &' /etc/rc.local
```

to **i**nsert it (i.e. place it before line 13); or

```
sed -i '13a\/home/me/dostuff.py &' /etc/rc.local
```

to **a**ppend it (i.e. place it after the current line 13).

---

Note that forward slashes aren't special in sed's `i` and `a` commands - only in regular expression matches such as `/pattern/d` or `s/pattern/replacement/` (although even there, they may be replaced by other delimiters such as `\%pattern%d` or `s#pattern#replacement#` - at least in GNU sed).